# With Google Analytics, is it possible to check a specific page in Multi-Channel conversion attribution?

Tags: google-analytics, conversions, event-tracking

I'm somewhat new to Google Analytics, and I'm trying to track all conversions that are assisted by a particular landing page, because I don't expect an instant purchase. I have e-commerce tracking set up.

Due to the constraints of the associated ad campaign, I can't include the source/medium code in the url when people go to the landing page, and all of my traffic to the landing page is likely to be direct, so I'm not sure how to tell Multi-Channel marketing that it's a significant page. I know how to add events to a page, but I'm still figuring out what they can and cannot do. Would creating a redirect from the landing url to an identical url+source/medium code work? Any advice on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

Tracking the final sale conversion is not the issue. Ecommerce reporting is functioning just fine on the site. I just want to report the landing page as an assist, whenever it shows up in the funnel, and I need to be able to do that across multiple visits.

Comment: An example would aid your question. What exactly qualifies a conversion on your website?

Comment: I'm just looking to track whether the page contributes to an ecommerce transaction. The cart on my store is separate from the landing page.

Comment: Why can't you add landing page URL as a secondary dimension in the multi-channel assisted conversions report to see if it assists a transaction (sorry if I'm not following what you're trying to achieve here).

Comment: Basically, the backstory is that an executive promised someone outside the company that "Everyone you drive to x-page who buys product y earns you z dollars." I'm trying desperately make good on that promise. What you suggest _seems_ to work. Does adding the dimension mean that if it's _ever_ visited by the customer, it gets reported?

Comment: No this would typically be the landing page they land on when arriving at your site (i.e the first page they view in the active session). Which I'm presuming is still no good?

Comment: Gotcha. No, that's not ideal. What about attaching an event to onload, then linking that to a goal? Can that be seen across sessions?

Comment: I'd also like to have some way to check conversion rate of people that visited a specific page, which may or may not have been their landing page on my site.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to see how much a page contributes to a sale and figuring out its value, look at the Page value metric under the Behaviour -> Site Content -> All pages report.

[You can read more about the page value metric here.](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2695658?hl=sv)

Also, I would recommend that you create a segment based on the campaigns you wrote about and looking at how that contributes and changes your page value numbers. This way you can isolate certain campaigns and correlate it to the landing pages.

Answer (score 0):

You have two courses of action.   Your first is as you already suggest: create a redirect from the landing URL to a URL with the correct tracking parameters on it.    That will work, and it is probably the simplest approach.

The other approach is to create a "Segment" for these users and view your e-commerce reporting with just that segment applied.  To create the segment you want:

1. View the report you are interested in
2. Click "+ Add Segment"
3. Click "+ New Segment"
4. Click "Conditions" under "Advanced"
5. Change the "Ad Content" drop down to "Landing Page"
6. Enter the relative URL for your landing page (eg `/my-landing`)
7. Name your segment something like "My Landing Users"
8. Click the blue "Save" button
9. Remove the "All Sessions" segment if it is still applied.